# Passing an array of models to route to display in view from controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

So I have a view that would show all of the rows available and display them.

A route calls the controller to fetch the data:

```
Route::get('/list', array('as' => 'index', [ContactListController::class, 'getContacts']));
```

I assign my controller to grab all of the rows using:

```
class ContactListController extends Controller
{
    public function getContacts()
    {
        $list = Contact::all();

        return view('list')->with($list);
    }
}
```

Then I display them in my view:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($list as $contact)
    <tr>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $contact->id }}">
        <td scope="row">{{ $contact->fname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $contact->lname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $contact->number }}</td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But the page says:
[image: ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given]
I would just like to display these data as a clickable table.

Please be easy on me since this is my first week of using Laravel ;)

Comment: What about `Route::get('/list', [ContactListController::class, 'getContacts']);`?

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: @FaizanAli The syntax of `fromAction` method in the screenshot of the error is Laravel 8 implementation. I already added the fix in the answer.

Comment: @FaizanAli it's 8.49.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/list', [YourController::class, 'yourMethod'])->name('index');
```

and then in the controller:

```
class ContactListController extends Controller
{
    public function getContacts()
    {
        $list = Contact::all();

        return view('list')->with('list', $list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using older route declaration with Laravel 8. The syntax of `fromAction` method in the screenshot of the error is Laravel 8 implementation.

Use either of this solutions:

```php
// Using PHP callable syntax...
Route::get('/list', [ContactListController::class, 'getContacts'])->name('index');

// Using string syntax...
Route::get('/list', 'ContactListController@getContacts')->name('index');
```

More info on this is on [Laravel 8.x Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade)